# AWS Lambda RDS too many connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I have connected an AWS Lambda function to Amazon RDS (MySQL). When the Lambda function is invoked 100 times simultaneously, there are almost 400 connections opened in RDS (as shown in RDS console). Why is this?

I checked the active connections using:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE DB = "MYDB";
```

All the connections are from Lambda containers. Does anyone know how Lambda containers act on simultaneous requests? Why are the containers not reused?

**Current Configuration:**

`var sequelize = new Sequelize('DB','username', 'password' ,{
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: port,
  host: host,
  pool: {
    max: 20,
    min: 0,
    idle: 300000
  }
});`

Even if one connection is opened per request it should be 100. How 400 connections are opened?

I'm using Sequelize. Node JS 6.9.1

> Note: Connection Happens only once outside Lambda Handler method

Comment: it might be possible that due to lots of same requests it scales its DB connections to the level expecting that this much load is coming.
Can you try holding connection and putting the next request a little time after

Comment: It may reuse the container, but that is not required for a web app right ? Concurrency is the basic principle of a web application. Why is Lambda require these many containers to handle 100 requests ?

Answer (score 2):

The lambda can have many concurrent executions.
So, more than one connection can be through by the lambda.

To fix this you need to change sequelize:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('DB','username', 'password' ,{
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: port,
  host: host,
  pool: {
    max: 1,
    min: 1,
    idle: 15000
  }
});
```

Keep the pool with only one connection, in this way the connection will be reused on the next execution and remember to dont close connection after the lambda execution.

Read [this](https://www.jeremydaly.com/reuse-database-connections-aws-lambda/) article about to reuse database connection on next executions.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize by defaults creates a connection pool, so it's creating 4 connections because it's designed to run as a long running service. You can disable this by setting `options.pool` to `false` see [the API reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html)

However as your application scales this is a fundamental problem with Lambda that won't go away. I recommend building a DB proxy layer in EC2 to terminate your db connections (i.e. using [ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com/)). It will then have a connection pool to the rds db.

The only way around this is to use dynamodb as your backend store.

Comment: The limitations with DynamoDb is the problem. We can't go for that. How to build the DB proxy layer ? Any reference ?

Comment: I've updated my comment on how to disable connection pooling in Sequelize. I've also added an example of a DB proxy you can use.

Comment: didn't get it. It is said to improve the caching and performance. How does it solve my connection problem ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS "new" solution for this problem seems to be RDS Proxy: https://aws.amazon.com/de/rds/proxy/

> RDS Proxy establishes and manages the necessary connection pools to your database so that your application creates fewer database connections.
>
> You can use RDS Proxy for any application that makes SQL calls to your database. But in the context of serverless, we focus on how this improves the Lambda experience.

https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: This is just quotes from AWS website?

Comment: yes quotes and links. RDS Proxy are relatively new so I wanted to reference them here for the future if other people encounter the same problem.

Comment: Proxies are now well out of preview and work great